# Why am I obtaining this error trying to conver my Angular project from a CSS based project to a SCSS one?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli

I am finding some problem trying to convert an Angular project using CSS into a project usinc SCSS SASS.

I was following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@ngubanethabo.ambrose/migrate-from-css-to-scss-stylesheets-for-existing-angular-application-d61f8061f5b7

So I performed this command:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

and now into my **angular.json** file I have the correct value:

"schematics": {
"@schematics/angular:component": {
"styleext": "scss"
}

Then I tried to use **renamer** tool as explained but not worked. I performed:

```
sudo renamer -d --path-element ext --find css -replace scss *
```

obtaining this error:

```
developer@developer-virtual-machine:~/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch/src$ sudo renamer -d --path-element ext --find css -replace scss *
Singular option already set [path-element=ext]
```

So I tried to manually do this operation:

- Renamed the Bootstrap CSS file into SCSS (I am not sure that this is correct):
  [image]
- Renamed the single component CSS file into SCSS

The problem is that when now I execute **ng serve** I am obtaining this error message:

```
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss ./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch/node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss' in '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch'
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss ./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch/node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss' in '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch'
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss ./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch/node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss' in '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch'
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss ./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss' in '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch'
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss ./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss' in '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch'
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss ./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss' in '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch'
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss ./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss' in '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch'
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss ./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch/src/styles.css' in '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch'
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I correctly convert it into a SCSS project?

**EDIT-1:** This is my **angular.json** file content:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "color_patch": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/color_patch",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss",
              "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss",
              "node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "color_patch:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "color_patch:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "color_patch:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "color_patch:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "color_patch:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "color_patch",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: angular version? can you show us the angular.json?

Comment: @izik Angular 9, I added the content of my angular.json file at the end of the original post

Comment: Doesn’t bootstrap already have a scss folder anyway..? That’s what I’m using..

Comment: Did you ever find the fix? Same problem here in V15 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75460296/angular-styles-scssngglobalstyle-module-build-failed-error

Answer (score 1):

try to update this part:

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

to this:

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

edit:

try to remove the first: `"schematics": {},`
and check your @imports

edit 2:

change this:

```
           "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss",
          "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss",
          "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss",
          "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss",
          "node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss",
          "node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss",
          "node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss",
          "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

to this:

```
           "styles": [
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.scss",
          "../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.scss",
          "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.scss",
          "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss",
          "../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.scss",
          "../node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.scss",
          "../node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.scss",
          "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.scss",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

Comment: Tried but same problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I changed the name of the folder and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `-replace` with `--replace` (double hyphen), everything is fine.